# Endpoint being called twice in Infinite scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, infinite-scroll

I'm using [Meta Fizzy Infinite Scroll](https://infinite-scroll.com/) to use a specified container as an infinite scroll container. I have two buttons, one button has a different endpoint than the second button. When one of the buttons are clicked, the infinite scroll container will populate.

```
<button data-api="/api/comments/1">First button</button>
<button data-api="/api/comments/2">Second button</button>

<div class="comments-container"></div>
```

Let's say the user clicks on the first button, and then later clicks on the second button. For the first time, we call the infinitescroll function normally. On the second button click, we destroy the first instance and reset the infinite scroll container that way the previous instance is destroyed.

```
    function CreateInfiniteScroll(endPoint) {

        let $container = $(endPoint.getFeedContainer()).infiniteScroll({
            path: function () {
                return endPoint.getEndPoint();
            },
            // load response as flat text
            responseType: 'text',
            status: '.scroll-status',
            history: false,
        });


        $container.on('load.infiniteScroll', function (event, response) {
            let data = JSON.parse(response);
            console.log(data);
     }
  }
```

When the second button is clicked, I run the following code:

```
                $(".comments-container").infiniteScroll('destroy');
                $(".comments-container").removeData('infiniteScroll');
CreateInfiniteScroll(new EndPoints(buttonEndpoint, ".comments-container"));
```

However, what happens is that I get duplicated posts on the second button click. The output to the console happens twice, even though I call the function only once. What is happening? How can I make it so that infiniteScroll resets 100%?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are subscribing twice to the same element, see this part:

```
$container.on('load.infiniteScroll', function (event, response) {
  let data = JSON.parse(response);
  console.log(data);
});
```

This means every time you call `CreateInfiniteScroll` a event handler for the `load.infiniteScroll` event is added to the div with the class `.comments-container`.
You could remove other event handlers before reattaching new event handlers like so in the `CreateInfiniteScroll` function:

```
$container.off('load.infiniteScroll'); // Remove all event handlers first
$container.on('load.infiniteScroll', function (event, response) {
  let data = JSON.parse(response);
  console.log(data);
});
```

Or you could add it to your button click code:

```
// Clean up
$(".comments-container").infiniteScroll('destroy');
$(".comments-container").removeData('infiniteScroll');
$(".comments-container").off('load.infiniteScroll'); // remove all other events handlers

// Reinstantiate infinite scroll
CreateInfiniteScroll(new EndPoints(buttonEndpoint, ".comments-container"));
```

Read more about JQuery's `.off` function [here](http://api.jquery.com/off/).

Comment: Just a quick question, it seems that all event handlers related to this container are now off...For example, there is a click handler related to this container and I can't click it

Comment: You can pass in the specific event handler that you would like to remove to the `.off ` function. I have updated my answer.